# ESLint - new line before return with IIFE

Tags: javascript, eslint

Have the following simple code

[image: Screenshot]

How to avoid this notification? I think this is because I used the IIFE function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try sticking a semi-colon before it `;(function`. Also you might think about moving to JSHint or even ESLint. JSLint just isn't very configurable.

Comment: It's not helped. Same error.

Comment: OP your title says JSLint but your code says its an ESLint error - which one are you asking about?

Comment: Note that if your js is meant for the browser then ESLint is correct to issue a warning. Your current code can unexpectedly cause a bug. For example, if you have another file "foo.js" that have the following content `var x = y` and your scrip tags are `<script src="foo.js"></script><script src="config.module.js"></script>` then your code will be interpreted as `var x = y(function(){/*your code*/})()` which calls function `y` with your function as argument, not an IIFE.

Comment: Please post code, not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable it for this specific case you can just add a disable comment on the same line: `(function(){ // eslint-disable-line newline-before-return`

If you'd like to disable it for the entire project, edit your `.eslintrc` file to add it to the `rules` section:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "newline-before-return": "off"
    }
}
```

More info on configuration here: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: I think he just confused the two, `newline-before-return` is an eslint rule

Comment: I want to disable it for all project.
But also I still need to have this rule for situation where we really used the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error for a rule that is not included in your current version of ESLint.  The rule was likely removed or renamed in an ESLint update.

Take a look at your `eslintrc` file.  Mine happens to be YAML, but yours could be JSON.  In the `rules` block, look for something like `newline-before-return: 1`.  Remove it.

Depending on your editor, you may have resave the JavaScript file to run the linting operation again, or close and reopen the editor to refresh the linter configuration.